# React Redux dispatch syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

Let's say I have an action:

```
export const getInfoFor = user => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch( fetchApi(user) );
    }
}

const fetchApi = user => dispatch => {
    return( dispatch({type: SET_USER}) )  <--- ??
}
```

My questions are, how did `dispatch` gets passed to the `return` in `fetchApi`? Maybe what's throwing me off is the double arrow functions in `fetchApi`.

The code works, but I want to understand why it works.

Comment: redux-thunk passes `dispatch` in when it calls the function. Line 4 of this file: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: Are you using Redux-Thunk?

Comment: yes, I'm using redux-thunk.

Comment: dispatch is the name of your argument.change it to myArg and you LL see

Comment: Yes, it could be any name... but my question is, how did that object got in there in the first place. I guess @NicholasTower answered it. still trying to understand redux-thunk code base.

Answer (score 2):

Your top-level function is intercepted by Redux-Thunk middleware and is passed `dispatch, getState, customValues`.

An example of the custom value ( from redux-thunk github )

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))
)

// later
function fetchUser(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    // you can use api here
  }
}
```

So, in short, it comes from Redux-Thunk middleware when you return a function.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js ( provided by @Nicholas Tower )

Answer (score 0):

Redux thunk is a small middleware that checks the `typeof` of the `action` that gets dispatched to the store. If the `typeof` action is a `function`, the middleware calls the function, passing dispatch as a parameter.

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js)